# Is it possible to have a drop capital in a tcolorbox?

Tags: tcolorbox, wrap, lettrine

Tried lettrine and did not work. Dropping seems not to be in texlive anymore.

Comment: A comment such as "did not work" is *not* actionable. Please provide a lot more detail about what you've tried so far, and please be more specific as to "did not work" entails. Do you get warning and/or error messages? If so, what do they say?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It would be better if you provided a minimal working example (MWE) of what you have tried.

It works fine here:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\begin{tcolorbox}
\lettrine{S}{ome} text. \lipsum[2]
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: Indeed it does! Sorry for the noise, must have messed up something in my previous tests and wanted to check with others if the thing was expected to work.